# Разбор Json Unity C#

Tags: c#, json, unity3d

Работаю в Unity. Нужна помощь в разборе json. Сейчас опишу проблему
Имеется вот такой json:

---

{"status":"ok","data":{"2125":{"nickname":"Test"}}}

---

Проблема заключается в том, что я не могу "дойти" до "nickname" из за id - 2125
заранее этот id у меня записан в public int userId.
Собственно вопрос, как мне разобрать Json до значения "nickname"?

Comment: может поможет https://app.quicktype.io/#r=json2csharp

Comment: Чем этот Json был создан тем его и нужно десериализовать. Есть разные алгоритмы и JsonUnity, если не ошибаюсь, в вашем случае не понимает, что такое 2125 т.к. это значение не соответствует какому-то имени поля

Comment: @M. Green, Json формируется на отдельном сервере, куда я кидаю запрос. Число 2125 является ключем и id пользователя. Изменить структуру json к сожалению не могу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мою проблему решил SimpleJSON.

```
var playerData = JSON.Parse(DataInfo.text);
Debug.Log(playerData["data"][userId.ToString()]["nickname"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, Nickname> data { get; set; }
}

public class Nickname
{
    public string nickname { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: спасибо за подсказку, но data не парсится, приходит null

Comment: UnityJson не умеет сериализовать словари или коллекции наследников (тип лист с классами B и C, которые наследуются от A он сериализует как лист объектов А)

Comment: @M.Green оу, не знал, что в юнити есть своя либа для json.

Comment: @Domi ты, видимо, используешь UnityJson? На System.Text.Json мой код работает нормально

Comment: @Александр всё верно я использую UnityJson. System.Text.Json я не могу подключить в юнити проект